# How to be resourceful in finance data science area?

Tags: finance

can I ask how to be resourceful in finance/banking data science area, here? What I mean being resourceful means, **knowing top data science trending in finance/banking area, knowing what are the creative companies doing in finance/banking area with data science, knowing major open data sources can be used in finance/banking in Canada**. Right now I am subscribing to several data science news but none of them focus on finance/banking area. If I could get daily/weekly news report related to data science development in finance/banking area will be great. My manager in the mid-term feedback for my internship suggested I should be more resourceful, so I really want to improve as fast as I could.

Any suggestions? Thank you very much!

Comment: this is most likely a better question to ask in [data science](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I work at Quandl, the premier source of open, commercial, and alternative datasets for investment professionals. Our clients include major banks and hedge funds. You can subscribe to our blog at https://www.quandl.com/blog to stay updated on the latest developments and thinking in the world of finance and data. Soon, we'll also be releasing a newsletter called Alternative Data Weekly where we'll share the most recent articles on the use of new, non-traditional data to inform investment decisions. Hope this helps. Good luck!